# How to check internet connection and display a default image

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am developing an app using phonegap.I want to display a default image in case there is no internet connection in the mobile.In this way if the user is not connected to the internet the  user instead of seeing alt text must see a default image.

`<img src="http://i1371.photobucket.com/albums/ag320/V3RT1AG0/the-amazing-spider-man-2-big-gam_zps01c52371.jpg" alt="Some Default Image">`

I know that we cant display image in alt attribute directly.But can we do it using jquery?
Thanks in advance

So this is what i want

1. Check internet connection using jquery
2. If connection is available then display image specified in src attribute
3. If not display a default image

Note:-I have lots of different images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can do like  this
      
img tag  has an attribute onerror event, you can use it
onerror will enable  when  can't get img

Comment: well I did something like this                                      `<img src="image.jpg" alt="image" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='alternateimage.jpg';" />`

Answer (score 0):

Add the connection plugin

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

Give an ID to the image tag

```
<img id="change_me" src="http://i1371.photobucket.com/albums/ag320/V3RT1AG0/the-amazing-spider-man-2-big-gam_zps01c52371.jpg" alt="Some Default Image">
```

Inside the device ready function

```
if(navigator.connection.type==0)
{
    change_image();
}
else if(navigator.connection.type=='none')
{
    change_image();
}
else
{

}
```

Now `change_image()` function

```
function change_image()
{

    image_url='img/default.jpg';
    jQuery('#change_me').attr('src', image_url);
    jQuery('#change_me').trigger('refresh');


}
```

Comment: Do i need to add the change_image function outside ready function and why did u leave the last else conditon blank.By device ready function you mean inside document.ready function right? Sorry I am a newbie in jquery.

Comment: In phonegap usually all works start after deviceready. You can say it is the cordova version of document.ready. To learn more see this http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready First you need to add that device ready listner, inside that device ready you can write those network finding code. `else` means you are connected with the internet. And yes you can put that change_image function outside deviceready function @AdityarajPednekar

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

function onOffline() {
    console.log("You have no Internet access");
}
```